# Firebase adding web app doesn't work - err [Reason: Deleted account when looking up robot. AppIdentity::DELETED]

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have created an app in the testing project and all worked fine, now when I am trying to replicate it in the production project in Firebase, it's throwing the following error. I cannot seem to find anything related online. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LMzj.png)

I am expecting to be able to add the web app into my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase support team has helped me to resolve this issue:

We need to override the bad OAuth client directly (the bad client may still exist, but will not be used for web apps anymore):

1. Create a new web OAuth client in Cloud Console with URIs and Authorized redirect specified (your project ID + firebaseapp.com)
2. In the Firebase console, Auth -> GoogleSignIn details -> Set the web client ID and secret from the new client

This worked for me.